# Integrating Twitter Bootstrap within a SpringMVC application

Tags: spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm starting out with building basic applications in SpringMVC. At the same time, I wanted to use some easy to setup UI frameworks like Twitter Bootstrap. But, No clue on how to set it up.

Question:

1. Where do I place the downloaded bootstrap folder?

[image]

[image]
[image]

What I have so far.

Comment: I am going to do the same would you tell me how was your experience of using Bootstrap and Spring MVC?  The question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732301/whats-the-best-method-to-implement-front-end-for-a-springmvc-application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would put these in src/main/resources NOT under WEB-INF. These don't need to be protected.

Also, make sure you tell Spring where they are in your dispatcher servlet config file as per the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources).

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

If you're using Spring security as well you'll need to make sure that the resources are not protected.

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
```

Comment: would it work if my resources were under webContent folder? if so how can i reference it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the .less files unless you plan to compile custom css. Maven projects, you typically place them in the resources folder. resources/assets/css and resources/assets/js

In the JSP:

```
<spring:url scope="page" var="bootstrapStylesheetUrl" value="/resources/assets/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<spring:url scope="page" var="bootstrapResponsiveStylesheetUrl" value="/resources/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css"/>
<spring:url scope="page" var="bootstrapJavascriptUrl" value="/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js"/>
```

And then in the head tag

```
<script src="${pageScope.bootstrapJavascriptUrl}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageScope.bootstrapStylesheetUrl}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageScope.bootstrapResponsiveStylesheetUrl}"/>
```

Also, don't forget to add the spring taglib to the top of your jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
```

In your spring servlet context config(productmgmt-servlet.xml) add the line:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="classpath:/"/>
```

Comment: the spring tags should go above the head tag. Also, create the WEB-INF/js and css directories. Drop the bootstrapp css files in /css and the javascript in /js. But yes that looks right.

Comment: create the WEB-INF/js and css directories. Drop the bootstrapp css files in /css and the javascript in /js. >> Is that why eclipse is given me a question mark?

Comment: I don't use Eclipse so I don't know why that is happening. Ultimately Alex is right though. In a Maven project, you typically place them in the resources folder.

Comment: Updated with using src/main/resources. I'm not positive about the location in the mvc:resource tag though.

Comment: the pageScope looks like a variable, where is that coming from?

Comment: It's a var available in spring mvc context. You can use it to grab variables within the page scope you normally wouldn't have access to.
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30946&seqNum=7